# Trying to present json data to client after getting it from server but only the first element is showing

Tags: node.js, json, firebase, rest, google-cloud-firestore

Related function

```
app.get('/api/profiles', (req, res) => {
    let citiesRef = db.collection('profiles');
    let allCities = citiesRef.get()
      .then(snapshot => {
        snapshot.forEach(doc => {
          res.send(doc.id+ '=>'+ doc.data());
        });
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log('Error getting documents', err);
      });
});
```

Expected result :

> 0wlyCuWKaZdM1G9fnT2N=>{"lastName":"Japan","email":"Tokyo@japan.com","userName":"Tokyo"}
>   mrlVDOpV8xQphsdlKdr4=>{"lastName":"Japan","email":"Tokyo@japan.com","userName":"Tokyo"}

Actual result:

> 0wlyCuWKaZdM1G9fnT2N=>{"email":"Tokyo@japan.com","userName":"Tokyo","lastName":"Japan"}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are only returning the first result in the response. you should return the entire array of users. see the following code:-

```
app.get('/api/profiles', (req, res) => {
    let citiesRef = db.collection('profiles');
     let responseArr=[]    //declare an empty array
    let allCities = citiesRef.get()
      .then(snapshot => {
        snapshot.forEach(doc => {
          responseArr.push(doc.id+ '=>'+ doc.data());   //push users into an array
        });
      res.send(responseArr);   //send response array containing all users
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log('Error getting documents', err);
      });
});
```